# A formula to find prime numbers in a loop

Tags: php, arrays, math, primes

I need to find prime numbers with for loop or while loop

I wrote this but this is wrong

```
<?php
$i = 1;
while($i<5)
{
    for($j=1; $j<=$i; $j++)
    {
        if ($j != 1 && $j != $i)
        {
            echo $i . "/" . $j . "=" . $i%$j . "<br />";
            if ($i%$j != 0)
            {
                echo $i . "<br />";
            }
        }
    }
    echo "<br />";
    $i += 1;
}
?>
```

Is there a way to divide a number with an array to find the remaining?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Here's a little function that I found: (http://icdif.com/computing/2011/09/15/check-number-prime-number/) Seemed to work for me!

```
function isPrime($num) {
    //1 is not prime. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number#Primality_of_one
    if($num == 1)
        return false;

    //2 is prime (the only even number that is prime)
    if($num == 2)
        return true;

    /**
     * if the number is divisible by two, then it's not prime and it's no longer
     * needed to check other even numbers
     */
    if($num % 2 == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Checks the odd numbers. If any of them is a factor, then it returns false.
     * The sqrt can be an aproximation, hence just for the sake of
     * security, one rounds it to the next highest integer value.
     */
    $ceil = ceil(sqrt($num));
    for($i = 3; $i <= $ceil; $i = $i + 2) {
        if($num % $i == 0)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Is getting the ceiling number of a square root required or is the floor sufficient enough? I'm having trouble thinking of a number that would be divisible by the ceiling of the square rooted number

Comment: ... `$sqrt = ceil(sqrt($num));` ...
if you calculate the sqrt outside of the for loop it will speed things up by ~400%, especially when checking lots of large numbers

Comment: Hi @Farkie, did you give it a try?  `neun@mono:~$ php test.php
    float(7.9089679718018)  
    neun@mono:~$ php test2.php  
    float(2.5886662006378)`
`

Comment: Can also be written as: `for($i = 3; $i <= $ceil; $i += 2) {`

Comment: Does it make sense to check /9 when number doesn't /3 ? I mean, there is no sense to `$num % $i` where $i is not prime itself.

Answer (score 13):

You can use this PHP function [`gmp_nextprime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-nextprime.php)

Comment: Although it's not always available :/

Comment: You need the GNU Multiple Precision(GMP) Mathematical Extension to be installed

Comment: In my tests it's kinda slow, too - didn't expect that. :/
Getting the prime numbers up to 100, 10.000 times, took almost 2s under PHP 5.6. The good answers here with for-loops achieve that in 200 - 400 ms.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a one-liner I found a while back to check for primes. It uses tally marks (unary math) to determine:

```
function is_prime_via_preg_expanded($number) {
    return !preg_match('/^1?$|^(11+?)\1+$/x', str_repeat('1', $number));
}
```

Check all numbers sequentially for primes:

```
$i=2; // start here (2 is the first prime)
while (1) { // neverending loop
    if (is_prime_via_preg_expanded($i)) echo $i." <br />\n";
    $i++;
}
```

To check only a range of numbers for primes like in the provided example:

```
$start = 2; // start here (2 is the first prime)
$end = 100;

$i=$start;
while ($i<=$end) {
    if (is_prime_via_preg_expanded($i)) echo $i." <br />\n";
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: This is friggin AWESOME Jeff!

Comment: This one is awesome for one time checks. But this function is much slower than the provided alternatives using loops.

Comment: Never did any comparisons, so that is very possible. This one is more for the interest of being a short one-liner with a rather unique method of solving the problem.

Answer (score 7):

This a basic implementation :

```
function prima($n){

  for($i=1;$i<=$n;$i++){  //numbers to be checked as prime

          $counter = 0; 
          for($j=1;$j<=$i;$j++){ //all divisible factors


                if($i % $j==0){ 

                      $counter++;
                }
          }

        //prime requires 2 rules ( divisible by 1 and divisible by itself)
        if($counter==2){

               print $i." is Prime <br/>";
        }
    }
} 

prima(20);  //find prime numbers from 1-20
```

This will output

```
 2 is Prime 
 3 is Prime 
 5 is Prime 
 7 is Prime 
 11 is Prime 
 13 is Prime 
 17 is Prime 
 19 is Prime
```

Complete Logic step-by-step and visual analogy here :  [Here](http://teknosains.com/i/menentukan-bilangan-prima-dengan-php)

Answer (score 3):

Without math function:

```
function isPrimeNumber($i) {
    $n = 2;
    while ($n < $i) {
        if ($i % $n) {
            $n++;
            continue;
        }

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I know it is too late, but I found that this solution is more elegant.

```
function isPrime($num)
{
    if ($num < 2) {
        return false;
    }
    for ($i = 2; $i <= $num / 2; $i++) {
        if ($num % $i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: The best answer, the simplest solution.

Comment: As a matter of facts using $i <= $num / 3; 
might speed this up especially for large numbers, but will never compete against gmp_nextprime() which provided me 664579 prime numbers in 39 seconds :)

Answer (score 2):

Anything who's sqrt() is false or any float value is prime number

Comment: this is not correct exactly. think of 6, whose `sqrt()` is a float, but itself is not a prime number. it should be; sqrt() of a prime number is always a float, which you can use to speed up the deciding process when looping through a lot of numbers.

Comment: @keune This is true in the example of an even number, but the function doesn't consider those in this case.  You are right, though; all numbers considered, that statement doesn't stand on its own.

Answer (score 1):

This, I believe, is a quite efficient routine, which lists all the primes up to 1000.

It tests each number ($x) in order to see if it has any factors (other than itself and 1, of course).

Mathematically it is not necessary to test all lower numbers as possible factors, only lower primes up to the square root of $x. This is enabled by storing primes as they are found in an array (which I think is the strategy the OP was referring to).

As soon as the first prime factor is found, we know that $x is not prime, and so no further testing of that value of $x is needed and we can break out of the foreach loop.

```
$primes = array();
for ($x = 2; $x <= 1000; $x++) {
    $xIsPrime = TRUE;
    $sqrtX = sqrt($x);
    foreach ($primes as $prime) if ($prime > $sqrtX || ((!($x % $prime)) && (!$xIsPrime = FALSE))) break;
    if ($xIsPrime) echo ($primes[] = $x)  . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Sieve_of_Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is simple and faster algorithm to find prime numbers.

```
function getPrimes($finish)
    {
        $number = 2;
        $range = range($number,$finish);
        $primes = array_combine($range,$range);
        while($number*$number < $finish){
            for($i=$number; $i<=$finish; $i+=$number){
                if($i==$number){
                    continue;
                }
                unset($primes[$i]);
            }
            $number = next($primes);
        }
        return $primes;
    }
```

Comment: `getPrimes(25)` returns 25 as a prime number, same for `getPrimes(49)` and 49. Only seems to happen when the finish point is a square number though and not for all of them.

Comment: Nice, one of the fastest answers here! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

    $n = 11;
    $o = $_POST["maxprime"];
    echo 'The script calculated the next primenumbers:</br>';
    echo '2, 3, 5, 7, ';
    while (true) { 
        $t = 6;
        while (true) { 
            if ($n % ($t - 1) == 0) {
                break;
            } 
            if ($n % ($t + 1) == 0) {
                break;
            }
            if ($t > sqrt($n)) {
                echo("$n,  "); 
                break;
            } 
            $t += 6; 
        }
        if (($n + 1) % 6 == 0) {
            $n += 2;
        } else {
            $n += 4;
        } 
        if ($n > $o) {
            break;
        }
    }

?>
```

http://www.primenumbergenerator.com/

Answer (score 1):

Below programs is simple with two for loops and ignores 1 and self values in iteration. It will print the prime numbers,

```php
function get_primenumbers($length) {
    //Ignore 1
    for($i = 2; $i <= $length; $i++){
        $prime = true;
        for($j = 2; $j <= $i; $j++){
            //Ignore same number
            if(($i != $j) && ($i % $j == 0)){
                $prime = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!$prime){
            echo "$i is not prime <br />";
        }else{
            echo "$i is prime <br />";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$num = 25;
echo "Value Hardcored ".$num."<br>";

for($i=2; $i<$num; $i++)
 {
  if($num%$i==0)
  {
   $Loop = true;
   echo "This is Composite Number";
   break; 
  }
  $Loop = false; 
 }

 if($Loop == false)
 {
  echo "Prime Number";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

i know this is coming kind of late, but hope it helps someone.

```
    function prime_number_finder($range)
    {
        $total_count=0;//intitialize the range keeper

        $i=1;//initialize the numbers to check

        while ($total_count<=$range)
        {
           $count=0;//initialize prime number inner count
           $k=$i;
           while ($k!=0)
           {

             if(($i%$k)==0)
             {
              $count++;
             }
              $k--;
           }
           //condition to check if a number is prime 
          if($count==2 || $count==1)
           {
            echo $i."</br>";//output the prime number;
            $total_count++;
            $i++;

           }
           //number is not prime
           if($count>2)
           {
             //$total_count++;
            $i++;
           }

        }
    }
```

//example 
   prime_number_finder(200);

Comment: Mind explaining what that last line of your answer is? "//example prime_number_finder(200);"

Comment: prime_number_finder(200) is just an example of how the function works, the example gets the first 200 prime numbers from the natural numbers.

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to invoke it?

Comment: yeah...to invoke the function

Comment: Ok, you should make that more clear next time. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

```
$n = 7;

if ($n == 1) {
    echo 'Not a Prime or Composite No.';
}

$set = 0;
for ($index = 2; $index <= $n/2; $index++) {

    if ($n % $index === 0) {
        $set = 1;
        break;
    }
}

if ($set) {
    echo 'Composite';
} else {
    echo 'Prime';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find prime numbers between 1 and 10000, using a closure in array_filter():

```
$start = 2;
$step = 10000;

$stop = $start + $step;
$candidates = range($start, $stop);    
for($num = 2; $num <= sqrt($stop); ++$num){                        
    $candidates = array_filter($candidates,
        function ($v) use (&$num){
             return ($v % $num) != 0 || $v == $num ;
        }
    );
}
print_r($candidates);
```

Edit: 1 is not a prime number

Comment: Nice except it gives 1 as a prime number.

Comment: Just start from 2 instead of 1, thanks for reporting!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to check if a number is prime is to see if it is divisible by any prime number before it. Pi(x) is the one I keep seeing everywhere... You can see a bit more information on Prime Counting on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function).

So the most efficient way I can think of at the moment is as follow:

```
class prime
{
    public $primes = [ 2, 3, 5, 7 ];
    public $not_prime = [ 1, 4, 6, 8, 9 ];
    public function is_prime( int $n )
    {
        if ( $n <= 1 ) return false;
        if ( in_array( $n, $this->primes ) ) return true;
        if ( in_array( $n, $this->not_prime ) ) return false;
        for( $i = 0; $i < count( array_slice( $this->primes, 0, $this->prime_count( $n ) ) ) || $i == $n; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $n % $this->primes[ $i ] == 0 ) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    public function build_primes_to( int $n )
    {
        for ( $i = end( $this->primes ) + 1; $i <= $n; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $this->is_prime( $i ) )
            {
                $this->primes[] = $i;
            }
            else
            {
                $this->not_prime[] = $i;
            }
        }
    }
    public function prime_count( $n )
    {
        $ln = log( $n );
        if ( $ln == 0 ) return 1;
        return intval( ceil( $n / $ln ) );
    }
}
```

Which isn't actually very efficient, well, not when it comes to building the list of prime numbers... I've been working on a better way of building the list [here](https://github.com/alexanderholman/Prime), though it would be just as easy and far more efficient to find a list online and use that.

Usage of the above would be along the lines of:

```
$find_to = 1000;
$prime = new prime();
$prime->build_primes_to( $find_to );
print "<pre>";
for ( $i = 1; $i < $find_to; $i++ )
{
    print "$i is " . ( !$prime->is_prime( $i ) ? "not " : "" ) . "prime\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is coming a bit late, but here's a simple program to help you do just what you're asking for...

```
<?php 
 //Prime Function
 function fn_prime($number) {
    $i = 2; $result = TRUE;
    while($i < $number) {
        if(!($number%$i)) {
            $result = FALSE;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    return $result;
 }

//Declare integer variable...
$k = 0;

//Start Loop up to any number of your choice for e.g. 200
while($k < 200) {
    if(fn_prime($k)) {
        echo "$k is a prime number<br/>";
    } else {
        echo "$k is not a prime number!<br/>";
    }
    $k++;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function prime_number($num){
    for( $j = 2; $j <= $num; $j++ )
    {
        for( $k = 2; $k < $j; $k++ )
        {
            if( $j % $k == 0 )
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if( $k == $j )
            echo "Prime Number : ".$j."<br>";
    }
}
prime_number(23);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Enchanced version of @Farkie answer made especially for checking primes in loops.

```
function isPrime_v2($num) {
    static $knownPrimes=[3]; // array to save known primes

    if($num == 1)
        return false;

    if($num == 2 || $num == 3) //added '3'
        return true;

    if($num % 2 == 0)
        return false;

    $ceil = ceil(sqrt($num)); //same purpose, good point from Farkie

    // Check against known primes to shorten operations
    // There is no sense to check agains numbers in between
    foreach($knownPrimesas $prime){
        if ($prime>$ceil)
            break;
        if($num===$prime)
            return true;
        if($num % $prime == 0)
            return false;
    }


    /**
     * end($knownPrimes) % 2 !==0 - mathematically guaranteed
     * start with latest known prime
     */
    for($i = end($knownPrimes)+2; $i <= $ceil; $i = $i + 2) {
        if($num % $i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    $knownPrimes[]=$num;
    return true;
}
```

Benchmark with phpfiddle.org. V1 - Farkie answer, V2 - Enchanced version

```
V1 (1 to 5,000,000): divisions=330 929 171; primes=348 513; time=21.243s
V2 (1 to 5,000,000): divisions=114 291 299; primes=348 513; time=10.357s
```

> **NOTE!** `isPrime_v2` function is applicable ONLY in case of looping from 3. Otherwise saved $knownPrimes array will have insufficient history.

Comment: You'll eventually run out of memory if you run this so large, but it will be faster (caching) :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another very simple but quiet effective approach:

```
function primes($n){

    $prime = range(2 , $n);

    foreach ($prime as $key => $value) {

        for ($i=2; $i < $value ; $i++) { 

            if (is_int($value / $i)) {

                unset($prime[$key]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    foreach ($prime as $value) {
        echo $value.'<br>';
    }
}

primes(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$limit=100;

$i=1;


outer:while($i<=$limit){
    $j=2;
    while($j<$i){
        if($i%$j==0){
            $i++;
            goto outer;
        }
        $j++;
    }
    echo $i;
    echo "<br/>";
    $i++;
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <form method="post" action="">
    <input type="number" name="demo" placeholder="Enter Any Number">
    <button type="submit" name="aqeela" > Prime or composite </button>
    </form>
    <br>
    <?php
      if(isset($_POST['aqeela']))
       {
         $nu=$_POST['demo'];
         if($nu==2)
       {
          echo "The Only Even Prime Number";
       }
       else
       {
         for($i=2; $i<$nu; $i++)
       {
         if($nu%$i==0)
       {    
         echo "This is Composite Number";
         break;  
       }
       else
       {    
         if($i==($nu-1))
       { 
         echo "Prime number";
       }    
      }  
     }
    }
   }
```