# php get the primary numbers in recursive function

Tags: php, function

I am just a newbie in php. Currently I am going through recursive function. So I want to know how to get all the prime numbers starting from 0 to 1000 in recursion. So can someone kindly tell me how to do this? This will also help me to get the idea about recursive function.

Comment: Here you've got the answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16763322/a-formula-to-find-prime-numbers-in-a-loop

Comment: wow I didn't know this. You've got as well the gmp_nextprime function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-nextprime.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Checks for prime numbers

function IsPrime($num) {    
    $No = 0 ;
    $Result  = 0 ; 

    for($Divisor = 2 ; $Divisor < $num; $Divisor++) {
        $Result = $num / $Divisor ; 
        if($Result != 1 && intval($Result) == $Result) { 
            $No = 1 ;
            break ; 
       } 
    }

    if($No != 1  )  {
        $Result = $num ; 
    }

    $No = 0;

    // If the only divisor is the number itself, it's prime 
    return ($Result == $num) ? 'Yes' : 'No' ; 
}  

for($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
    echo "<b> Testing number $i  : </b>"  ; 
    echo $i." is a prime number? ". IsPrime($i)."<br />";
}

  ?>
```

Comment: This is not recursive

Comment: Also, the result ist not totally correct, your function states that 1 is a prime number.

Comment: I don't think this is recursive function. I want the recursive function

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this..

```
<?php

function dispPrime($i)
{
    if($i<=1000)
    {
        if(gmp_prob_prime($i)===2) // Checks the number for prime.
        {
            echo "$i is a Prime Number";
        }
        $i++;
        dispPrime($i);  // Recursive call (Function that calls itself)
    }
    else{ exit;}

}

dispPrime(0);
```

Comment: If you're going to spoonfeed a lazy OP, at least add an explanation of what you're doing. It's clear the OP doesn't know how this will work, so _explain it_.

Comment: Using `gmp_prob_prime()` also probably is less useful to OP than doing it by hand.