# Made a series of prime numbers using php

Tags: php, numbers, primes

I made this code to create a series of prime numbers using php

```
$number = 53;

for ($i=0; $i<=$number; $i++)
{
    if ( $i == 2 )
    {
        echo "$i ";
    }
    else if ( $i == 3 )
    {
        echo "$i ";
    }
    else if ($i % 2 != 0 && $i % 3 != 0)
    {
        echo "$i ";
    }
}
```

and the result: 1 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 25 29 31 35 37 41 43 47 49 53 
why number `25`, `35` and `49` still appear.?

or maybe made like this code ?

```html
$number = 53;

for( $i = 2; $i <= $number; $i++ )
{
    for( $k = 2; $k < $i; $k++ )
    {
        if( $i % $k == 0 )
    {
    break;
    }

    }
    if( $k == $i )
    echo $i." ";
}
```

but I want to include number 1 in the result

Comment: 1 is not a prime number

Comment: Because neither 25, nor 35, nor 49 are divisible by 2 or by 3.

Comment: Blackhole answerred it correctly. It can be fun to play with, but if you just need a working function, use gmp_nextprime() on php >= 5.6.
Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16763322/a-formula-to-find-prime-numbers-in-a-loop

Comment: thanks Jay Blanchard for edited. thanks @twicejr for the info

Answer (score 0):

25 % 2 = 1

25 % 3 = 1

As such, it displays the number.

Your function does not display prime numbers; rather, it displays number which are not divisible by 2 or 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this bit of code.

```
<?php
$number = 983;
$i = 0;
while($i <= $number)
{
    $prime = true;
    if($i != 0 && $i != 1 && $i != 2)
    {
        echo 'Number: ' . $i;
        // echo $i .'</br>';
        $x = range(2,$i-1);

        foreach($x as $try => $value)
        {
            if(($i % $value) === 0)
            {
                $prime = false;
            }
        }

        if($prime == true)
        {
            echo ' is a prime';
        }
    }
    $i++;
    echo '</br>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I know this is coming a bit late, but here's a function that can help you do this exactly...

```
<?php 
 //Prime Function
 function fn_prime($number) {
    $i = 2; $result = TRUE;
    while($i < $number) {
        if(!($number%$i)) {
            $result = FALSE;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    return $result;
 }

//Declare integer variable...
$k = 0;

//Start Loop up to any number of your choice for e.g. 200
while($k < 200) {
    if(fn_prime($k)) {
        echo "$k is a prime number<br/>";
    } else {
        echo "$k is not a prime number!<br/>";
    }
    $k++;
}

?>
```