# Using PHP post for simple prime number program

Tags: php, primes

I can make a simple set of IF statements to find whether a number is either a composite or a prime (even though I think a function would be better suited).

However, I can't echo out either statement below when I try to up-my-game and use post.

There are no syntax errors here, just flawed logic. Problem is, where is the flaw??

Thanks for any advice.

```
<form>
<form name="PrimeCalculator" method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="input"> Enter any number to see if it's a Prime or Composite<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calculate">
</form>

<?PHP
if($_POST['submit'] == "Calculate"){
  $num=$_POST["input"];
    for ($i = 2; $i <= $num-1; $i++) {
      if ($num % $i == 0) {
      $value= True;
      }
}
if ($value) {
   echo 'The Number '. $num . ' Is A Composite';
}  else {
   echo 'The Number '. $num . ' Is A Prime';
   } 
}
?>
```

Comment: try $value = false; before the first if

Comment: Are you sure that the values are getting passed correctly to your PHP code via POST? Try var_dump($_POST) maybe ?

Comment: You might be better off using a function to check for prime which returns true or false. Your code would be lot more cleaner and easier to understand then. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16763322/a-formula-to-find-prime-numbers-in-a-loop

Comment: @dbinns66 - hi! no luck. The code for prime works.Thinking its the post stuff I've tagged on

Comment: @Maximus2012 -Hi. Yeah, I recognize a function would be better but using baby steps - master Ifs, get the basics of post

Comment: Try removing an extra <form> tag from your form. It would also be helpful if you could indicate what exactly is not working in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error actually is in the html, remove the first `<form>` tag and it should work, though your code is throwing

```
E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined variable: value -- at line 14
```

when entering a prime number as $value isn't set then.

You can use

```
if (isset($value) && $value)
```

for the check instead.

```
<form name="PrimeCalculator" method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="input"> Enter any number to see if it's a Prime or Composite<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calculate">
</form>
```

Comment: Ah..that works - thank you! I cant accept your answer until 5 mins have passed.  Could you explain why the initial tag was preventing the code from working - I need to make sure that I don't make the same mistake twice.

Comment: because you are submitting an empty form - the first one opened.

Comment: @MissDizy you can't have 2 <form> tags like that.

Comment: Right - thanxs. Will keep that in mind. Really appreciate you help!