# PHP - check if number is prime

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a function which checks whether the number is prime or not. BUT I want this function to echo to the user 'prime' or 'NOT prime' - and that's where my problem starts. 
Let me show you my code:

```
class IsPrime
{       
    function check($num)
    {
        for ($i = 2; $i < $num; $i++)
        {
            if ($num % $i == 0) 
            {
                echo 'NOT prime';
                break;
            }               
        }
        echo 'Prime';           
    }       
}

$x = new IsPrime();
$x->check(4);
```

The problem is that when I put any prime number - it works correctly, but when I put any not prime number - it also echos second echo, sth like this: `'NOT prime prime'`.

How can I make it echo only the right answer ?

Comment: you have toi put it inside with in `else`

Comment: show me - i've tried and couldnt do that

Comment: Look at http://php.net/manual/function.gmp-prob-prime.php

Comment: $sergey - cant you see that I want to create a function ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-prob-prime.php

Comment: @Piter  no response from you. deleting my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A formula to find prime numbers in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16763322/a-formula-to-find-prime-numbers-in-a-loop)

Comment: General advice: functions that `echo` stuff are not the most practical design anyway. I'd expect that a method called `IsPrime::check()` would return a boolean—in such case the bug is trivial to fix because `return` will exit the loop.

Answer (score 10):

in <s>54</s> 59 bytes:

```php
function is_prime($n){for($i=$n;--$i&&$n%$i;);return$i==1;}
```

loops `$i` down from `$n-1` until it finds a divisor of `$n`; `$n` is prime if that divisor is 1.

---

add 10 bytes for much better performance:

```php
function is_prime($n){for($i=$n**.5|1;$i&&$n%$i--;);return!$i&&$n>1;}
```

loops `$i` from (approx.) `sqrt($n)` to `1` looking for a divisor with a post-decrement on $i.
If the divisor is `1`, `$i` will be `0` at the end, and `!$i` gives `true`.

This solition uses a trick: For `$n=2` or `3`, `$i` will be initialized to 1 → loop exits in first iteration. For larger even square roots (`$n**.5|0`), `|1` serves as `+1`. For odd square roots, `+1` is not needed because: if `$n`  is divisible by `root+1`, it is also divisible by `2`. Unfortunately, this can cost a lot of iterations; so you better

---

add another 7 bytes for even better performance:

```php
function is_prime($n){for($i=~-$n**.5|0;$i&&$n%$i--;);return!$i&$n>2|$n==2;}
```

`$n=2` needs a special case here: inital `$i=2` divides `$n=2` → final `$i=1` → returns `false`.

Adding `1` to `$n` instead of the square root is enough to avoid failures; but:

---

I did not count the iterations but only tested time consumption; and that only in TiO instead of a controlled environment. The difference between the last two versions was smaller than the deviation between several runs.
Significant test results may be added later.

Comment: In 2106 in an interpreter script lang, do you think is it matter those some bytes? It's just makes your code totally undreadable for other developers.

Comment: @vaso123 Why waste space only because You have plenty?

Comment: because readability is one of the most important thing, more important than length of code.

Comment: Btw: Add 5 more bytes for optimal speed: init `$i` to `1+$n**.5|0` (or 1+floor(sqrt($n)))

Comment: The question was "why my code echoes twice?" (hint: a break instead of a return). You wrote the perfect answer to "How do I write slow and sloppy code for finding prime numbers saving a few script bytes?".

Comment: @FrancescoMM Yup. That´s called code golf. Still perfect in some way. :D But the perfect answer to the OP is `return`, not `exit`, instead of `break`. (See amin saffar´s comment on the first answer.)

Comment: @Titus ok, but your code is far from perfect. If we really want performance finding primes, we have to enter the magic mathematical kingdom of preudo-primes and the primality tests of Baillie-PSW or Miller–Rabin, or even without, you can run  testing one number out of 4, for example. You would instantly see how unuseful all the solutions presented here are. Saving bytes is always good, but saving bytes on high level code typing at the expense of running cycles is not.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_and_Solovay%E2%80%93Strassen_primality_test

Comment: Great solution @Titus

Answer (score 3):

This could be a long procedure if the number is really a prime number. There is a shorter procedure as well.
We need not run the for loop upto the number itself. Instead, we can run it upto the **Highest Integer less than or equal to the square root of the number.**

```
class IsPrime
{       
     function check($num)
     {
        $bCheck = True;


        $highestIntegralSquareRoot = floor(sqrt($num));
        for ($i = 2; $i <= $highestIntegralSquareRoot; $i++)
        {
            if ($num % $i == 0) 
            {
                 $bCheck = False;
                 break;
            }               
        }
       if $bCheck 
          echo 'Prime';           
       else
          echo 'NOT prime'; 
     }       
  }

 $x = new IsPrime();
 $x->check(97);
```

Now, in the above, if we check check whether 97 is prime or not (actually, it is), then the loop need not run from 2 to 97, but only from 2 to 9. (Square root of 97 is 9.8488578018, and highest integer less than or equal to that is 9. Similarly, we can check for number 121 (this is not a prime number, as it is divisible by 11). The limit will be increased from 2 to 11 in a similar matter. And so on.
Actually, we need to check the divisibility of the number by the smaller prime numbers in the vicinity, but that would be more complex.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

As many answer pointed out, your logic code has a problem: when you get `i` such that `num % i == 0`, you print "NOT prime" and quit the loop, after that, you still print "Prime". Some guys moved `echo "Prime"` in `if-else`, it is still wrong. One way to approach, for example,

```
class IsPrime
{       
     function check($num)
     {
        $bCheck = True; 
        for ($i = 2; $i < $num; $i++)
        {
            if ($num % $i == 0) 
            {
                 $bCheck = False;
                 break;
            }               
        }
       if $bCheck 
          echo 'Prime';           
       else
          echo 'NOT prime'; 
     }       
  }

 $x = new IsPrime();
 $x->check(4);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
function primeCheck($num)
{
    if ($num == 1)
        return false;
        for ($i = 2; $i <= $num/2; $i++)
        {
            if ($num % $i == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    return true;
}

$primeNumber = primeCheck(17);

if ($primeNumber == true)
{
    echo "Is Prime";
}
else
{
    echo "Is Not Prime";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The break is only breaking the for loop,
use `return;` instead. it will exit the function

Comment: I've found that myself a few minutes before Your post - but thats the correct answer. cheers

Answer (score 1):

> **Just** use return:

```
class IsPrime
{       
function check($num)
{
    for ($i = 2; $i < $num; $i++)
    {
        if ($num % $i == 0) 
        {
            echo 'NOT prime';
            return; // that you need
        }               
    }
    echo 'Prime';           
}       
}

$x = new IsPrime();
$x->check(4);
```

<kbd>**[if/else notation](http://php.net/manual/control-structures.elseif.php)

 [return notation](http://php.net/manual/function.return.php)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You can find prime numbers and non prime numbers from 1 to your limit and its count.

```
public function prime_checker($count){
  $counter=0;
  $no_prime=0;
  for($i=2 ; $i<=$count; $i++ ){
    for($j=2 ; $j<$i ; $j++ ){
      if($i % $j == 0){
        echo $i.'is not prime<br/>';
        $no_prime=$i;
        break;
      }
    }
    if($i != $no_prime){
      $prime_numbers[$counter]=$i;
      $counter=$counter+1;
    }    
  }
  echo '<br/>'.$counter.'prime numbers<br/><br/>';
  for($i=0 ; $i<$counter ; $i++ ){
    echo $prime_numbers[$i].' is  prime<br/>';
  }
}
```

Comment: Please you need to add an explanation to your answer

Comment: you can find prime numbers and non prime numbers from 1 to your limit and also print  count of prime numbers

Comment: How on earth this could be a reply to the original question? The question was "why does my code echo twice?" You reply with some slow and sloppy code to list all prime numbers... It just belongs somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

You can check number is prime or not & without using loop with this function:

```js
function is_prime($p) {

    $r1 = $p%2;
    $r2 = $p%3;
    $r3 = $p%5;

    return ($p > 1) &&  (($r1 >= 1) && ($r2 >= 1) && ($r3 >= 1)) ||  in_array($p, [2,3,5]);
}
```

Comment: This is NOT correct at all. It returns true for 49 (7*7), 77 (7*11), 121 (11*11) and so on

Comment: Not divisible by 2, 3 and 5 does not make a number prime! What about any number divisible by 7 or 11 or 13...?

Answer (score 0):

**Please Check this**

```
class IsPrime
{       
    function check($num)
    {
        for ($i = 2; $i < $num; $i++)
        {
            if ($num % $i == 0) 
            {
                return 'NOT prime';

            }

        }
        return 'Prime';           
    }       
}

$x = new IsPrime();
$result = $x->check(4);
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
class IsPrime
{       
function check($num)
{
    for ($i = 2; $i < $num; $i++)
    {
        if ($num % $i == 0) 
        {
            echo 'NOT prime';
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Prime';
        }
    }
    //echo 'Prime';           
}       
}
  $x = new IsPrime();
  $x->check(3);
```

Comment: why to try? any comment?

Answer (score 0):

Put else part otherwise it will always `return Prime`

```
    for ($i = 2; $i < $num; $i++)
{
    if ($num % $i == 0)
    {
        echo 'NOT prime';
        break;
    }
    echo 'Prime';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print "Prime" as a return to the function to ensure nothing is printed during the function except for the condition for "NOT prime".

```
   class IsPrime
    {       
        function check($num)
        {
            for ($i = 2; $i < $num; $i++)
            {
                if ($num % $i == 0) 
                {
                    echo 'NOT prime';
                    break;
                }               
            }
          return "Prime";         
        }       
    }

    $x = new IsPrime();
    echo $x->check(4);
```

Comment: if use $x->check(3); it will be return, not print

Comment: I have added an echo prior to the function which will print out "Prime". But I guess this answer is similar to most of the answers here.

Answer (score 0):

```
$num = ceil(sqrt($num));

$is_prime = true;
for($j=3; $j<=$num; $j=$j+2){
    if($i%$j == 0){         
        $is_prime = false;
        break;
    }
}

if($is_prime){
    echo "No is Prime";
}
```

Note: Start loop from 2 as it is the only even prime no. Increment with 2 as no even no is a prime no.

=> Code for finding all prime no in range (2-100)

```
$limit = 100; $arr = array(2);
for($i=3; $i<=$limit; $i=$i+2){

    $num = ceil(sqrt($i));

    $is_prime = true;
    for($j=3; $j<=$num; $j=$j+2){
        if($i%$j == 0){         
            $is_prime = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if($is_prime){
        $arr[] = $i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a similar one where a user types in a number and PHP checks if the number is prime or not.

HTML

```
<p>See if your number is a prime number</p>

<form>

<input type='number' name='number'>

<input type='submit' value='Check!'>

</form>
```

PHP

```
if ($_GET) {

    $i = 2;

    $isPrime = true;

    while ($i < $_GET['number']) {

        if ($_GET['number'] % $i == 0){

            // Number is NOT prime
            $isPrime = false;

        }

        $i++;
    }

    if ($isPrime){

        echo '<p>'.$i.' is a prime number!';

    } else {

        echo '<p>'.$i.' is NOT a prime number';

    }

}
```

Hopefully this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't make a mistake here:

```
for ($i = 2; $i < $num; $i++)
```

and then:

```
if ($num % $i == 0) return false;
```

2 % 2 equals 0 and then 2 will result as NOT prime.

Next, you don't have to check even numbers, so after you check if $num == 2, better performance is:

```
for ($i = 3; $i < $num/2; $i += 2)
```

Notice $num/2 - you don't have to check beyond that point.
And even better is:

```
for ($i = 3; $i*$i <= $num; $i += 2)
```

This is because when you check for division with 2 and 3 all other NON prime numbers are product of two (or more) prime numbers (e.g. 49 = 7*7 or 55 = 5*11). In the worst case scenario your $i pointer would reach a square root of $num (like in 49 = 7*7). That's why you check until $i*$i <= $num.

Answer (score 0):

### PHP 4

You can do enough random checks (`$i=20`) to bring the false positive probability very low.

```php
/*
    The Rabin/Miller Algorithm.
*/

function is_prime($n, $i = 10)
{
    if (($n == 1) == ($n & 1)) return $n == 2;
    if ($n < 51529) // will not be repeated 7 times (deletable condition)
        return ($n & 1) & (($n < 6) * 42 + 0x208A2882) >> $n % 30 && ($n < 49 || ($n % 7 && $n % 11 && $n % 13 && $n % 17 && $n % 19 && $n % 23 && $n % 29 && $n % 31 && $n % 37 && ($n < 1369 || ($n % 41 && $n % 43 && $n % 47 && $n % 53 && $n % 59 && $n % 61 && $n % 67 && $n % 71 && $n % 73 && ( $n < 6241 || ($n % 79 && $n % 83 && $n % 89 && $n % 97 && $n % 101 && $n % 103 && $n % 107 && $n % 109 && $n % 113 && ( $n < 16129 || ($n % 127 && $n % 131 && $n % 137 && $n % 139 && $n % 149 && $n % 151 && $n % 157 && $n % 163 && $n % 167 && ( $n < 29929 || ($n % 173 && $n % 179 && $n % 181 && $n % 191 && $n % 193 && $n % 197 && $n % 199 && $n % 211 && $n % 223))))))))));
    for ($a = $c = $n - 1, $d = $c - 1, $b = 0; !($a & 1); $a >>= 1, ++$b) ;
    for (; $i--;) {
        do for ($e = $f = mt_rand(1, $d), $g = $n; ($e %= $g) && ($g %= $e);) ;
        while ($e > 1 && $g > 1);
        for ($e = $g = 1; $g <= $a; $g <<= 1) ;
        for (; $g >>= 1; $e = ($e * $e) % $n, $g & $a && ($e = ($f * $e) % $n)) ;
        if ($e == 1) continue;
        for ($r = $b; $r-- ; $e = ($e * $e) % $n)
            if ($e == $c) continue 2;
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

echo is_prime(2147483647); // 1
echo is_prime(PHP_MAJOR_VERSION); // You Know
```

This **PHP4** variant of the Fermat test has a polynomial runtime in `log($n)`.
Just use it for small numbers, when `$n < 2147483647`, otherwise it's [gmp_prob_prime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-prob-prime.php).

Thank You.

Answer (score -1):

```
function is_prime($number)
{
    return (bool) !preg_match('/^1?$|^(11+?)\1+$/x', str_repeat('1', $number));
}
```

Comment: Just trolling around? :)

Answer (score -1):

Entire program is correct . But only you should do replace **break** with **exit** function .because break only used to exit loop which are enclosed with curly braces {} and exit are used to stop the execution of an entire script.

```
class IsPrime
{   
    function check($num)
    {
        for ($i = 2; $i < $num; $i++)
        {
            if ($num % $i == 0) 
            {
                echo 'NOT prime';
                break;
            }               
        }
        echo 'Prime';           
    }       
}

$x = new IsPrime();
$x->check(4);
```

Comment: `return` is better than `exit` because we are in function body.

Answer (score -2):

That is my solution. If you put the condition in the loop and break after it, it's never going to finish with the check.

```
$num = rand ( 1, 1000 );

$notPri = null;

for($check = 2; $check < $num; $check ++) {

      if ($num % $check == 0) {
          $notPri ++;
         }
       }

if ($neEpri == 0) {

    echo $num . "<br>Prime!";

} else {
     echo $num . "<br>Not a prime!";
   }
```