# How to find backward primes within a range of integers?

Tags: php, function, range, primes, palindrome

I'm trying to solve a backward prime question.

Following is the question:

> Find all Backwards Read Primes between two positive given numbers (both inclusive), the second one being greater than the first one. The resulting array or the resulting string will be ordered following the natural order of the prime numbers.

Example

```
backwardsPrime(2, 100) => [13, 17, 31, 37, 71, 73, 79, 97] 
backwardsPrime(9900, 10000) => [9923, 9931, 9941, 9967]
```

I tried doing something like this:

```
public function backwardPrime()
{
    $start = 7000;
    $stop = 7100;

    $ans = [];

    while($start <= $stop)
    {
        if($start > 10)
        {
            if($start !== $this->reverse($start))
            {
                if($this->isPrime($start) && $this->isPrime($this->reverse($start)))
                {
                    array_push($ans, $start);
                }
            }
        }
        $start++;
    }
    return $ans;
}

public function reverse($num)
{
    $reverse = 0;
    while($num > 0)
    {
        $reverse = $reverse * 10;
        $reverse = $reverse + $num%10;
        $num = (int)($num/10);
    }
    return $reverse;
}

public function isPrime($num)
{
    if($num == 1 || $num == 2 || $num == 3)
        return true;
    elseif ($num%2 == 0 || $num%3 == 0)
        return false;
    else
    {
        $i=5;
        while($i<=$num/2)
        {
            if($num%$i===0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            $i++;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I'm able to get the appropriate answer but while doing the same in single function I'm not able to get it:

```
public function backwardPrimes()
{
    $start = 7000;
    $stop = 7100;
    $ans = [];
    while($start <= $stop)
    {
        $isStartPrime = true;
        $isReversePrime = true;
        if($start > 10)
        {
            $reverse = 0;
            $num = $start;
            while($num > 0)
            {
                $reverse = $reverse * 10;
                $reverse = $reverse + $num%10;
                $num = (int)($num/10);
            }
            if($start !== $reverse)
            {
                if($start%2 != 0 && $start%3 != 0)
                {
                    $i =5;
                    while($i<=$start/2)
                    {
                        if($start%$i === 0)
                        {
                            $isStartPrime = false;
                            break;
                        }
                        $i++;
                    }
                }
                if($reverse%2 != 0 && $reverse%3 != 0)
                {
                    $i =5;
                    while($i<=$reverse/2)
                    {
                        if($reverse%$i === 0)
                        {
                            $isReversePrime = false;
                            break;
                        }
                        $i++;
                    }
                }
                if($isStartPrime && $isReversePrime)
                {
                    array_push($ans, $start);
                }
            }
        }
        $start++;
    }
    return $ans;
}
```

I don't know where I'm having mistake, guide me.

Thanks.

Comment: I used a different approach to solve the problem, hope it will help.

Comment: for your function i did not know  how did you came with `$start = 7000;
    $stop = 7100;` it a little bit hard to guess

Comment: @yoeunes I'm just using the dummy data for calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An emirp ("prime" spelled backwards) is a prime whose (base 10) reversal is also prime, but which is not a palindromic prime. in other words
Backwards Read Primes are primes that when read backwards in base 10 (from right to left) are a different prime. (This rules out primes which are palindromes.)

try this short solution in which I use two helper function `reverse` and `isPrime` :

1. `isPrime`: Thanks to @Jeff Clayton for his method to test prime numbers, for more information click the link below https://stackoverflow.com/a/24769490/4369087
2. `reverse`: that use the php function [strrev()][1], this method take a string a reverse it, we'll use this trick to reverse a number by converting it to a string reverse it and converting back to an integer.
3. `backwardsPrime`: this last function's job is itterating over a range of numbers from $min value to $max value and test if the number if a prime number and it's reverse is a prime number as well and it's not a palindrome number if all of those conditions are true then we addit to the result array.

### implementation

```
function isPrime($number) 
{
  return !preg_match('/^1?$|^(11+?)\1+$/x', str_repeat('1', $number));
}

function reverse($n) 
{
    return (int) strrev((string) $n);
}

function backwardsPrime($min, $max)
{
    $result = [];

    foreach(range($min, $max) as $number) {
        $reverse = reverse($number);
        if($reverse !== $number  && isPrime($number) && isPrime($reverse)) {    
           $result[] = $number;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

echo "<pre>";          
print_r(backwardsPrime(2, 100));
print_r(backwardsPrime(9900, 10000));
```

output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 13
    [1] => 17
    [2] => 31
    [3] => 37
    [4] => 71
    [5] => 73
    [6] => 79
    [7] => 97
)



   Array
(
    [0] => 9923
    [1] => 9931
    [2] => 9941
    [3] => 9967
)
```

you can even optimize the backwardsPrime function like this :

```
function backwardsPrime($min, $max)
{
    $result = [];

    foreach(range($min, $max) as $number) {
        $reverse = reverse($number);
        if($reverse !== $number && !in_array($number, $result) && isPrime($number) && isPrime($reverse)) {  
           $result[] = $number;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you sir @mickmackusa, I'll explain in a moment in details

Comment: @yoeunes Thanks for the answer, your optimized code is not giving appropriate answer. I mean the second code.

Comment: yeah for sure, i just made a sort for the final array

Comment: I tried dummy data `[9900, 10000 ]` and I'm getting output of `[9923,3299,9931,1399,9941,1499,9967,7699]`

Comment: @yoeunes Question asks to find the numbers between the range given like suppose you have starting number is 9900 and end number is 10000 then you need to have prime number belonging to this range only and your answer have `1399,1499,3299,7699` which is not valid. As in the example I've mentioned `backwardsPrime(9900, 10000) => [9923, 9931, 9941, 9967]` which do not have `1399,1499,3299,7699` value.

Comment: my bad sorry i forget the $reverse number in the result array

Comment: Just remove second $result [] declaration after if statement, then no need to sort.

Comment: @mickmackusa Yes, my question was not for palindromic prime.

Comment: you welcome bro, a spécial thanks to @mickmackusa for his help advice.

Comment: You don't need the sort call at the end right?  Because the foreach iterates min to max.

Comment: Primes with two or more digits can only end in 1, 3, 7 or 9.  Hence emirps can only start with those digits.